# Will IE9 run on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11, downgrade

I need to install IE9 on Windows 10, but cannot.  I keep getting a message "Internet Explorer 9 is already installed on this system".

I found an article on how to downgrade from IE10 TO IE9, but it didn't work on Windows 10 http://anyfindings.blogspot.com/2013/04/restore-ie9-after-installing-ie10.html

I removed windows 11 and all installed updates for internet explore, but no luck.

BTW, I support a web app that uses data islands.  That's why I still need IE9.

Comment: Does IE9 compatibility mode in IE11 work? IE on Win10 supports all the IE compatibility modes, so in most cases that should do the job for you. You can add a header to the page telling the browser to use IE9 mode.

Comment: IE9 compatibility mode is available in IE11 (via debug tool).  However, IE9 compat mode doesn't support xml data islands.  If there was some way to do that I'd love to know how.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I need to install IE9 on Windows 10, but cannot. I keep getting a
>   message "Internet Explorer 9 is already installed on this system".

This is by design.  You cannot run IE9 on Windows 8, Windows 8.1, or any version or future version/build of Windows 10 unless you use a virtual machine and install a version of Windows other then those versions on said virtual machine.

> BTW, I support a web app that uses data islands. That's why I still
>   need IE9.

So use one of the [trial virtual machines](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) that Microsoft offers for FREE for exactly this purpose.  If the virtual machine option isn't acceptable you will need to install Windows 7 on the machine and use that option instead.

> I removed windows 11 and all installed updates for Internet Explorer,
>   but no luck.

The instructions you followed only work if a previous version of IE existed before you installed IE11 on said machine.  In your case since IE11 is the only version of IE that will ever exist or can exist on Windows 10 and for that reason it is only possible to uninstall/disable IE11.